# Authentication using Single-sign-on

Tags: web-services, authentication, soap, web, single-sign-on

In my web service project i need to include a authentication part using single-sign-on and spring. I am new to this technology. I was searching for an sample application for past few days, but i couldn't find it. Please help me by suggesting any tutorials. It will be a great help for me

Answer (score 0):

For single-sign-on, the web service method for authentication should take username and password as parameters, and this authentication method should return a MAC ('Message Authentication Code', also named alternatively 'Authentication Token').

All the subsequent calls to other web service methods should contain this MAC so that the web service methods know which user is calling them.

```
//example pseudo code for authentication
string web_service_auth(string User_Name,string Password) {
   ...
   string Mac;
   if (access_accepted(User_Name,Password))
     Mac = ...;
   else
     Mac = "access-denied";
   return Mac;
}

//example pseudo code for other methods
string web_service_get_my_info(string Mac) {
  if (!mac_is_valid(Mac))
    return "invalid-mac";
  ...
  string User_Name = mac_to_username(Mac);
  string Info      = get_user_info(User_Name);
  return Info;
}
```

Comment: Mr. Paul thanks for your valuable input, can u suggest any tutorials in which i can learn to implement the sso.

Comment: which language are you going to use to create the web service methods?

Comment: I am using java. By using this i need to give an authentication to my web service by creating token

Comment: I would recommend you to look at a framework called SAML for the implementation of SSO.
You will only need to learn the XML parsing APIs in java.
Google uses SAML:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

SAMl documentation can be found out here

https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=security

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input